# How to identify which application is used to start excel process in task manager

Tags: excel, vb6

My vb application is used to generate the excel reports.During the last run it got failed in between but the excel process still running in the background on server.

The problem is there are some other applications that uses excel process to generate reports. I need to terminate the particular instance of excel which was still running at the background.

Comment: Perhaps that may help: http://www.pbdr.com/vbtips/api/FindCloseAPI.htm - I use that code to terminate processes in scripts.

Comment: This may be helpful to code change in future but i need to kill the process which is running now?

Comment: It DOES: if you run the code, it will kill all the windows with defined title. I use it for killing suspended processes of my custom test software

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the task manager but Sysinternals Process Explorer would give you that information. It lists all processes in a tree view displaying parent/child process hierarchies. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: I think that, technically, the excel process is not a child process of the application. It starts independent and is only controlled by the starting application. If I am wrong, please correct me

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question before and the bad news is, that there is no straightforward way to do that.
What can be done: When you start up excel in your application store the PID (if available, I am not sure) and / or the path of the created document. In case of an error, terminate the specific excel process by PID. Or if that is not possible: iterate over all open excel instances and find the one which has opened the path - than kill that instance. The latter approach is problematic in multi user environments, as Excel does not react well when used by multiple applications.

The best way would be to get rid of excel on the server altogether and move to an independent excel-writing library like EPPLUS or Aspose.Cells or other alternatives.  But I do not know, if these libraries are still available for VB6. Please note, that Microsoft advises against using Office on a server